# How to prevent escaping when adding JSON object with jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am working with jq and I am trying to add a new JSON object to a new key to an existing file.

I have the following JSON file, **foobarbaz.json** :

```
{
    "example":{
        "name": "stackOverflowQuestion"
    }
}
```

I want to add a new entry under example, so to get the following output in **foobar.json**

```
{
    "example": {
        "name": "stackOverflowQuestion",
        "new": {
            "newfield": {
                "key": "value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following commands in the terminal:

```
$ tempvar='{"newfield":{"key":"value"}}'
$ cat foobarbaz.json | jq '.example.new=env.tempvar' > foobar.json
```

However, the output in **foobar.json** is somewhat unexpected:

```
{
  "example": {
    "name": "stackOverflowQuestion",
    "new": "{\"newfield\":{\"key\":\"value\"}}"
  }
}
```

Why does jq wrap the curly brackets with quotes, and why does it escape the double quotes?

Comment: It's adding the literal content *as a string*, which is right/proper/appropriate, because that content *is* a string until you convert it to be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fromjson` to convert your string (the format *all* environment variables are in!) to the corresponding data structure, by decoding it as JSON content.

```
tempvar='{"newfield":{"key":"value"}}' jq '.example.new=(env.tempvar | fromjson)' <<'EOF'
{
    "example":{
        "name": "stackOverflowQuestion"
    }
}
EOF
```

...emits as output:

```
{
  "example": {
    "name": "stackOverflowQuestion",
    "new": {
      "newfield": {
        "key": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--argjson` option to pass the pre-existing JSON snippet as a variable to the filter.

```
$ jq --argjson x "$tempvar" '.example.new=$x' foobarbaz.json
{
  "example": {
    "name": "stackOverflowQuestion",
    "new": {
      "newfield": {
        "key": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `tempvar` isn't strictly necessary and can be dropped, if you are only defining it for use with the filter:

```
$ jq '.example.new={newfield: {key: "value"}}' foobarbaz.json
{
  "example": {
    "name": "stackOverflowQuestion",
    "new": {
      "newfield": {
        "key": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```